# Address validation in customer's account

Tags: customer-account, validation, customer-address

I need to implement an address validation in the address book in customer's account. The validation should be like the one that happens during the checkout, that checks if the given address exists or not. In the checkout it happens by calling the saveBilling() method in this url: http://site_domain.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/saveBilling/

Is there any way of making the same kind of validation in customer's account? I have been trying for 2 weeks to achieve this, but with no good results.

Help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Edit: I mean same validation that goes on during checkout. For example: "An exact street name could not be found!". When debugging using firebug, we see that URL ttp://site_domain.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/saveBilling/ returns the above error message. This url is passed as the third parameter in this line of code: var billing = new Billing('co-billing-form', 'getUrl('checkout/onepage/getAddress') ?>address/', 'getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveBilling') ?>'); I try to do the same thing in the customer address book, but the validation won't happen.
I get the 403 error, saying i have no permission to access this url. Maybe someone could tell me in general how do you validate the billing address on the address book on a customer's account? I'm stuck with this and i have no clue, at all

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? Often people are on the right track, but just need a little tweak.

Comment: how  will you check  given address exists or not. ?